# Maemo / Symbian and external libraries

Tags: symbian, ocr, nokia, tesseract, maemo

How can I know, whether an external library can be compiled to work on a different platform? the library for instance is [tesseract-ocr](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)

And if it possible, how do I do this?? (Basically I would like to create a Qt application that uses this library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out, try building the library yourself. At the moment your question is quite broad. Post new questions when you have something more specific to ask.

If building the library fails, it is most probably due to some unsupported dependencies that you need to port first yourself.

Porting to Maemo is probably straightforward as it is a Debian-based environment and supports all the build tools such as autotools.

Symbian doesn't have autotools. Perhaps the fastest way to get started there is to first configure and build the library on e.g. cygwin and then generate the required bld.inf and .mmp files to build it on Symbian.

You can link your Qt application to regular C/C++ libraries. Just include the necessary header files in your code and link to the library using `LIBS += -lfoo` in your .pro file.